# injection fault Renault Megane 2 1.5dci

Tags: diesel

I have a Renault Megane 2 1.5 dci with 150,000 km on the clock.

Sign the injection fault, then the engine stops or makes rattling noises. I noticed that the hose back fuel for air bubbles that appear periodically. When I hand pump the Priming Pump, then the engine starts to work better and nearly stops, while after travelling 20-30 km, again the injection fault appears.

I did a test nozzle to return from their fuel and all returned the same amount of diesel. I changed the camshaft and crankshaft Sensor. Before changing the camshaft sensor I had problems starting the engine. Now this problem is solved.

Comment: What is your actual question? I had a 2002 Megane2 1.9DCI that had many many many faults. Beware when changing injectors that they need coding with the ECU.

Comment: No follow up from OP to comment.